# creating text file with regards to file names

Tags: scripts, text-processing

I have a text file (digit.txt) consisting of one column includes three digit numbers whose range are 001-...365. In the same directory, I have data text files. The file name of these data files as follows, `jplg3240.18i`. Only the `jplg` part is constant. I need to order `jplg` data files w.r.t. the numbers in the digit.txt file using the first 5-7 characters of the file names and store them in another text file. For example:

```
digit.txt=
005
301
350
005
010

data files= jplg001.18i.txt, jplg005.18i.txt, jplg301.18i.txt, jplg350.18i.txt,jplg010.18i.txt, jplg365.18i.txt
```

Output file should be this one:

```
output=
jplg005.18i
jplg301.18i
jplg350.18i
jplg005.18i
jplg010.18i
```

Comment: in short you need to cycle on the content of digit.txt and for the only matched data generate a second file with the list of complete filename, is it that correct?

Comment: yes it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the while cycle could be good for reach your goal:

```bsh
while read element
do
    if [ -f jplg${element}* ]; then
        echo jplg${element}* >> datafiles.txt
    fi
done < digit.txt
```

Code is supposed to be run in to the path were the files are and give you as per result a file list in the file datafiles.txt with the complete name of the file if was matched in the list in the file digit.txt

Comment: I think my question was understood slightly wrong. I have lots of data files in the directory and the name of these files starts with jplg. The contents of these data files are not related the jplg string.

Comment: Update the answer, now only jplg* data will added in the datafiles.txt, anyway was not clear in you original question to me. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you question is concatenate the data from the files listed in digit.txt then an answer is:

```
ls jplg* | grep -f digit.txt | xargs cat >out.dat
```

In slo-mo:

- `ls jplg*`: lists a superset of all the files you want (you can make that more restrictive if needed)
- `grep -f digit.txt` keeps only the lines that contain one number in `digit.txt` (this assumes that the three digits don't appear anywhere else in file names)
- `xargs cat`: applies `cat` to all the files listed in the grep output